# How to find, stop and disable a Windows service using Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, service

I am trying to find a service, stop it and then disable it remotely using Powershell. It can find and stop but cannot disable. For disabling, I have to run the `Set-Service` command separately. Can it be done in one line?

The following code-snippet will stop the **Print Spooler** service, but will not disable it:

```
$ip = "10.10.10.10"
$svc_name = "Spooler"
get-service -ComputerName $ip | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $svc_name} |  Stop-Service | Set-Service -StartupType  Disabled
```

The following code-snippet will stop and disable the **Print Spooler** service:

```
$ip = "10.10.10.10"
$svc_name = "Spooler"
get-service -ComputerName $ip | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $svc_name} |  Stop-Service
Set-Service $svc_name -StartupType  Disabled
```

Powershell version is `5.1.14393.2969`.

**Edit:**
The following line will also find and disable. So, it looks like I can give two instructions with pipeline.

```
get-service -ComputerName $ip | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $svc_name} | Set-Service -StartupType  Disabled
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to use `Set-Service` to set the startup type, as outlined in your question:

```
Set-Service -StartupType Disabled $svc_name
```

If you want to do it in "one line", you can use the `-PassThru` argument on `Stop-Service` to return the service object which can then be sent down the pipeline (you also don't need a `Where-Object` clause, `Get-Service` can filter on service name as well):

```
Get-Service -ComputerName $ip $svc_name | Stop-Service -PassThru | Set-Service -StartupType Disabled
```

You had this close in your original question, but it didn't work because you didn't use the
`-PassThru` parameter on `Stop-Service`. As a note, many cmdlets that don't return an object by default do include a `-PassThru` parameter to return an object that can further processed if necessary, this isn't limited to `Stop-Service` by any means.

Comment: ```--PassThru```. Helped. In fact, ```Where-Object``` was in my script for other conditions. I excluded those conditions for simplifying the question, but did not just remove it.

Comment: Still, now you return a lesser number of services over the network. You can still do more local processing with a `Where-Object` clause.

Answer (score 2):

Bender's answer works in PowerShell 5.1, but the `-ComputerName` parameter was removed from the `Get-Service` cmdlet in PowerShell 6+. If you're trying to do this in pwsh.exe (i.e. PowerShell 6+), you can use code like the following:

```
[string[]] $servers = @('server1', 'server2, 'server3')

[scriptblock] $disableServiceScriptBlock = {
    [string] $serviceName = 'SERVICE NAME TO DISABLE GOES HERE'
    Stop-Service -Name $serviceName
    Set-Service -Name $serviceName -StartupType Disabled
}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servers -ScriptBlock $disableServiceScriptBlock
```

Here's a longer code snippet with better error reporting so you know what server an error occurred on:

```
[string[]] $servers = @('server1', 'server2, 'server3')

[scriptblock] $disableServiceScriptBlock = {
    [string] $serviceName = 'SERVICE NAME TO DISABLE GOES HERE'
    Stop-Service -Name $serviceName -ErrorVariable stopError -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Set-Service -Name $serviceName -StartupType Disabled -ErrorVariable disableError -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    # If an error occurred, report which server it occurred on with the error message.
    [string] $computerName = $Env:ComputerName
    if ($stopError)
    {
        Write-Error "$computerName : Stop Error: $stopError"
    }
    if ($disableError)
    {
        Write-Error "$computerName : Disable Error: $disableError"
    }
}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servers -ScriptBlock $disableServiceScriptBlock
```

Answer (score -1):

```
***Stopping both Windows Firewall and Windows Defender Firewall***
$date = get-date -uformat "%m%d%y-%H"
$day =  Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd
$dayold = Get-Date -Format "%M%d%y"
$today = (Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd)+"-"+(get-date -uformat %H) 
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
$ServerList = (Get-adcomputer -SearchBase "OU=site,OU=servers,DC=subdomain,DC=domain,DC=root" -filter {name -like "*cont*ext*"} -SearchScope Subtree -Properties Name) |select name
$ServerList=$ServerList.name
(Test-Connection -ComputerName $env:LOGONSERVER.Remove(0,2) -Count 1 -quiet)|Out-Null
foreach ($server in $ServerList){
if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $server -Count 1 -quiet){
$result = (get-service -ComputerName $server -name MpsSvc |select *)
if($result.Status -eq "Running")
    {
    get-service -ComputerName $server -name MpsSvc |stop-service -Force
    get-service -ComputerName $server -name MpsSvc |set-service -ComputerName $server -StartupType Disabled
    }
    elseif($result.StartType -ne "Disabled"){
    set-service -ComputerName $server -name MpsSvc -StartupType "Disabled"
    }
        $result = (get-service -ComputerName $server -name MpsSvc |select *)
        $server+": "+"The "+$result.DisplayName+" is "+$result.Status+" and "+$result.StartType
    }
    }
```